# How can Rpi interface BME280 / BMP280 pressure and humidity sensor?

Tags: i2c, pi-b+

I have a BME280 sensor (this exact ebay item https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/322638558861) wired directly with jumpers (not soldered) to a RPi B+. I have enabled I2C and installed the tools. The wiring is as per this diagram:

[image: diagram from https://github.com/fivdi/bme280]

When I run `i2cdetect -y 1` I get the following:

```
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

So my Pi cannot seem to find the sensor and thus I'm stuck.

In a probably foolish excitement I first wired the sensor incorrectly and while the RPi was powered on. The first wiring followed this diagram:

[image: from https://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2016/07/using-bme280-i2c-temperature-pressure-sensor-in-python/]

I believe I wired the power in first then ground then the other 2 pins. Would doing this with the RPi power on have fried my sensor? If it is fried is there any way to test this? Is there some other way to debug any issue here?

**Edit**

[image: jumpers attached to sensor]
[image: jumpers to Pi]

Comment: We need a clear photo showing the connections between the Pi and the sensor.

Comment: @joan have added. Photos a bit poor sorry but surprisingly difficult to take! I think they should show everything. (Also to note if you are concerned by the connection to the sensor I checked the voltage with a multimeter between the 3x3 and the ground from the short end of the double male jumpers and there didnt seem to be any issue so I think connecting like that is stable)

Comment: Have you soldered the pins into the board or are they just pressed through (and not making a contact with the PCB traces)?

Comment: Hi @iiz, welcome and nice to meet you. Ah, let me see. Your pictures seem to show three different versions of Rpi. I guess the fritzing pics are for reference only, and only your photo shows the exact wiring and Rpi version (Rpi3B+ v1.2 2014). Please also confirm if you are using buster, stretch, or jessie.

Comment: On second thought, your Rpi Model B+ marked 2014 should be VERSION ONE. And anyway that should be good enough to play with sensors such as BME280, whether you are using old raspbian versions jessie or wheezy. In other words, I don't suggest you to upgrade any hardware or software. Let me search this and other forums to refresh my memory on BMP180 and BME280, before I am sure if I can give you some suggestions. See you later. Cheers.

Comment: Ah, I forgot one thing. To gear my suggestions to your level of hardware knowledge and skills, I need to know if you have and know how to use a multi-meter to measure voltage and resistance (never mind current for now), and if you have heard about the Ohm's Law (V = I x R). It would be nice if you have some experience in Arduino and Rpi, and know how to blink a LED (never mind about button for now). I assume you have not messed around with other I2C toys before.  Pleas let me know otherwise. Cheers.

Comment: Now let us come back to you "i2cdetect -y 1"-detect-nothing-problem. This is a common newbie problem. (1) I forgot if your old rpi is using I2C bus 0. This is unlikely, but no harm using "i2cdetect -y 0", just to make sure. (2) BME280 is an improved version of BMP180. You might like to search with "BMP180" this or other forums to see how other newbies solve (or give up) similar problems. An example is this one: (1) Rpi3 BMP180 Barometer Sensor Interface Problem - Asked 4 months ago Viewed 268 times
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60274562/rpi3-bmp180-barometer-sensor-interface-problem.

Comment: BAD NEWS - I googled further and found that your module is not 5V I2C input, because there is a 5V to 3V3 level down converter at the input side. In other words, you nee to use a 3V3 to 5V level up converter at the Rpi I2C pins. You can use an 5V Arduino to verify my guess, or you can use a 3V3 to 5V converter for the Rpi I2C pin/signals.

Comment: Or you can ask eBay to confirm, and return the 5V module to replace a 3V3 module.

Comment: Thanks @tlfong01 for your help. Quick answers: I have latest headless raspian flashed days ago. My hardware knowledge is fairly low. I did some blinking LEDs stuff with aurduino years ago and my theoretical understanding isnt great. I can use a multimeter but generally need to know what im looking for. Looks like you are correct that I have a 5v version of the sensor. I will confirm with seller. It is not worth the trouble to use a 5v sensor when 3v3 equivalents exist? Or is the conversation you speak of in the software?

Comment: @Dougie they aren’t soldered but Im fairly confident they are making decent contact. Maybe Im wrong about that? Is there a preferred way to connect sensor boards like that non permanently?

Comment: I am 90% sure that your module with 4 pin connector is 5V I2C signal compatible, which is good for 5V Arduino or similar MCUs. The following TaoBao ad is another hint: https://shop468430569.world.taobao.com/search.htm?orderType=&viewType=grid&keyword=bme280&lowPrice=&highPrice=. Cheers.

Comment: Well, 5V I2C or 3V3 I2C each has pros and cons. For newbies I do recommend to start with 3V3, saving the trouble of doing logical level conversion (BTW, the conversion is purely hardware! You can search AdaFruit for a newbie friendly tutorial). And if you know how to blink an Arduino LED, and also how to use a multi-meter to measure voltage and resistance, that is more than enough to start exploring BME280. Good luck and cheers.

Comment: It will NOT have a chance of working until you solder in the header pins. I checked the datasheet DO NOT connect it to 5V. Max Vin is 3.6V.

Comment: @Dougie you were correct. I just needed to solder on the header pins to get a reliable connection. Now it shows up and works. If you want to post that as an answer I will accept it otherwise I will answer the question myself in a few days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your I2C sensor isn't detected is that you've not soldered the header pins into the breakout board. There won't be a connection between Vin, GND, SDA & SCL to your RPi.

The BME280 on your breakout board runs on 3.6V max, so don't connect Vin to either pin#2 or pin#4 use pin#1 or pin#17.

Answer (score 0):

***Answer***

*(1) The OP says he is playing with the eBay BME280 shown below.*

---

[image: bme280]

---

*(2) Now let us get to know BME280.*

[image: bme 280 2]

---

*(3) I googled for a schematic, and found there should be two types of BME280 modules, one with 6 or 7 pin header, for 5V I2C input, another with 4 pin header, for 3V3 I2C input.*

[image: bmp280 3v3]

[image: bmp280 5v]

I would recommend the OP to check out if he indeed has a 5V input version, and replace it with a 3V3 input version which is more newbie friendly.

---

***References***

(1) [Rpi3 BMP180 Barometer Sensor Interface Problem - SO Q&E, Asked 2020feb18, Viewed 268 times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60274562/rpi3-bmp180-barometer-sensor-interface-problem)

(2) [bme280pi 1.0.1 - pypi 2020jun24](https://pypi.org/project/bme280pi/1.0.1/)

(3) [Using the BME280 I2C Temperature and Pressure Sensor in Python - Matt 2016jul21](https://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2016/07/using-bme280-i2c-temperature-pressure-sensor-in-python/)

---